# Customise input format in hadoop and map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to implement the customise input format(record reader). When key  is a text and  value is text(paragraph)

Comment: When asking, please mention what you've tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

extends FileInputFormat in the class which you want to make your custom input format like if you class name is CustomTextInputFormat , and each line of your input data file have exact two values which are coma (,) seperated, and you want to take first one as key and second one as value then below is the code

```
public class CustomTextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, Text> {

@Override
public RecordReader<Text, Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit input,
        TaskAttemptContext ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CustomTextRecordReader reader=new CustomTextRecordReader();
    reader.initialize(input, ctx);
    return reader;
}

}


import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;<br>
import org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader;<br>

public class CustomTextRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text, Text> {

LineReader lineReader;
Text key;
Text line=new Text();
Text value;
Configuration conf;
FileSplit split;
@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        int status=lineReader.readLine(line);
        if(status<=0){
            return false;
        }
        String[] str =line.toString().split(",");
        if(str.length!=2){
            throw new Exception("Illegal number of arguments");
        }
        key = new Text(str[0].trim());
        value = str[1];

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return true;
}

@Override
public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext ctx)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    this.split=(FileSplit)split;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    conf = ctx.getConfiguration();
    Path path=this.split.getPath();
    FileSystem fs=path.getFileSystem(conf);
    FSDataInputStream in=null;
    try{
        in = fs.open(path);
        lineReader = new LineReader(in,conf);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return key;
}

@Override
public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return value;
}

@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

Basically the main logic in **nextKeyValue** mehod in which you read the line from the file and then you can apply you own logic to create key and value as you require.
For more information below is the code in Mapper's run method which is run by framefork to get your key and value and pass to the map method

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     setup(context);
     while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
         map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
     }
     cleanup(context);
}
```